# What is maximum purchaseToken length provided by google after in app purchases in android?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

Can anyone tell me the exact length of purchaseToken provided by google after successfull in app purchase in andorid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This token is an opaque character sequence that may be up to **1,000** characters long.

Comment: Could you please share where this anwser came from?

Comment: It is actually provided in the documentation (scroll to the first json): https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Purchase

Comment: The link is broken. I cannot find the JSON in the page where it redirects now.

Comment: The link is to depricated API. I need for Google Play Billing Library.